# efficiently reading digit matrix without delimiter in python

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I have a file which contains digit [0-9] matrix without delimiter with shape (N, M). N would be ~50k, M would be ~50k.
A small version of matrix file will be for example, `mat.txt`

```
0012230012000
0012230002300
0012230004200
```

Right now I am using the following code, but I am not so satified with the speed.

```py
def read_int_mat(path):
    """
    Read a matrix of integer with [0-9], and with no delimiter.
    """
    with open(path) as f:
        mat = np.array(
            [np.array([int(c) for c in line.strip()]) for line in f.readlines()],
            dtype=np.int8,
        )
    return mat
```

Edit:
Here is a mini benchmark

```py
import numpy as np
def read_int_mat(path):
    """
    Read a matrix of integer with [0-9], and with no delimiter.
    """
    with open(path) as f:
        mat = np.array(
            [np.array([int(c) for c in line.strip()]) for line in f.readlines()],
            dtype=np.int8,
        )
    return mat

%timeit read_int_mat("mat.txt")
%timeit np.genfromtxt("mat.txt", delimiter=1, dtype="int8")

print(read_int_mat("mat.txt"))
print(np.genfromtxt("mat.txt", delimiter=1, dtype="int8"))
```

Outputs are:

```
61.6 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
327 µs ± 4.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
[[0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 2 3 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 4 2 0 0]]
[[0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 2 3 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 4 2 0 0]]
```

Is there any thing I could try to further speed it up. Would Cython help here? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What should be the output of `print(mat)` in this example?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for the question, I update an edit, it would be a (N, M) numpy matrix

Comment: Yes, can you *show* it? *Which* (N, M) numpy matrix would it be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt), for example:

The file (13 columns):

```
0012230012000
0012230002300
0012230004200
```

Then:

```
x = np.genfromtxt("file.txt", delimiter=1, dtype="int8")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[[0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 2 3 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 4 2 0 0]]
```

---

EDIT: Version with `np.fromiter` and opening the file in binary mode:

```
def read_npfromiter(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return np.array(
            [np.fromiter((chr(c) for c in l.strip()), dtype="int8") for l in f],
        )
```

---

Benchmark on file with shape `(168, 9360)`:

```
from timeit import timeit


def read_int_mat(path):
    """
    Read a matrix of integer with [0-9], and with no delimiter.
    """
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        mat = np.array(
            [
                np.array([int(c) for c in line.strip()])
                for line in f.readlines()
            ],
            dtype=np.int8,
        )
    return mat


def read_npfromiter(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return np.array(
            [np.fromiter((chr(c) for c in l.strip()), dtype="int8") for l in f],
        )


def f1(f):
    return np.genfromtxt(
        f, delimiter=1, dtype="int8", autostrip=False, encoding="ascii"
    )


def f2(f):
    return read_int_mat(f)


def f3(f):
    return read_npfromiter(f)


t1 = timeit(lambda: f1("file.txt"), number=1)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2("file.txt"), number=1)
t3 = timeit(lambda: f3("file.txt"), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Result:

```
1.0680423599551432
0.28135157003998756
0.19099885696778074
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I remember trying genfromtxt, the performance is actually less satified. I updated the description with a mini benchmark.

Comment: @david I've added version with `np.fromiter` and opening the file in binary mode

Comment: Thanks your new function is indeed faster. Do you think there will be some way to further improve this? Would Cython be a good thing to try?

Comment: @david Yes, implementing the functionality in low-level language such as C (Cython) will be faster - to skip creating Python's temporary lists, unicode conversion, etc... also, preallocating the arrays in memory in advance will help too.

Comment: May I ask what would be a good practice to preallocating the array? I am not sure if the number of rows can be inferred quickly. Seems possible since the file is pretty structured. Do you know anyway such that one function can both handle vanilla text and compressed files (suffix with .gz)

Comment: @david Maybe it will be good idea to ask here on StackOverflow under the C language tag. Then you can call the function using for example `ctypes` module. But this is all complicated topic (including reading from .gz files). Numpy also supports [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#complex-arrays) - maybe it's worth to look at that too.